# is there any méthode to read/write excel files with VBA using typescript in angular?

Tags: angular, excel, typescript, vba

i have an excel template .xlsm with a vba code, and i wanna take data from my angular application and paste it into a specific cells, and sheets

i tried using XLSX from 'xlsx' to read, and write into excel files, but i lost the Code VBA that i had in the first excel file.
using XLSX i got a binary copy of the excel file, and i wrote the specific fields into there cells and sheets, but i lost the vba code and the layout

Comment: It is impossible to give advice without code or other details. See https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/csf/features/vba/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link for sheetJS, i don't have any error in the code, and the structure of my application i need a specific library to read and write into excel file,with out lossing the vba code on it